# How to bind event to appended element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

When loading the page I bind the click event of a list of element.
then I append new items to the same list with same element but event not binds with the newly added elements.

This problem with me from a long time and I usually reload that location after I appended element, but it is not giving me the benefit of using ajax.

Common answer with sample code will appreciated.

Comment: Nice Profile Photo! Where is your code you have tried so far???

Comment: You are probably looking for event delegation, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Use `$(document).on(event, selector, function)` for dynamic elements